# map users with a mail address

Tags: email, postfix, cyrus

I'm using Postfix with Cyrus Imap.

The login is done by authenticating with GSS-API (SSO).

The format of mail accounts for all users is *username@ejemplo.org*.

For a few users want your mail account follow another format.

Example that pepe has as pepe1@ejemplo.org as mail account.

All who receive mail from pepe have as sender pepe1@ejemplo.org.

And that all mail sent to pepe1@ejemplo.org receive pepe.

I have the following:

**In /etc/postfix/main.cf add**

```
virtual_alias_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/virtual
canonical_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/canonical
sender_canonical_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/canonical
recipient_canonical_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/canonical
```

**/etc/postfix/virtual**

```
pepe1@ejemplo.org pepe@ejemplo.org
pepe2@ejemplo.org        pepe@ejemplo.org
```

**/etc/postfix/canonical**

```
pepe@ejemplo.org pepe1@ejemplo.org
pepe    pepe1
```

Also run the following lines:

```
postmap /etc/postfix/virtual
postmap /etc/postfix/canonical
```

If sending an email to pepe1@ejemplo.org get what I want, pepe@ejemplo.org can read the mail.

But if I send an email from pepe@ejemplo.org you receive the mail from pe@ejemplo.org and NO pepe1 as I want it to display.

Any help?, Thanks for help.

Comment: This solved.
In a few minutes I publish my solution.

Answer (score 1):

Answer over here instead of a comment to make it clearer.

1)

In nano /etc/postfix/virtual

```
pepe1@ejemplo.org username@ejemplo.org
```

2)

In /etc/postfix/header_checks:

```
/^From:.*username@ejemplo\.org/ REPLACE From:pepe1@ejemplo.org
```

3) Run:

```
postmap /etc/postfix/virtual
postmap /etc/postfix/sender_canonical
```

4) In /etc/postfix/main.cf add:

```
virtual_alias_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/virtual
header_checks = regexp:/etc/postfix/header_checks
```

5) postfix restart:

```
 postfix stop
 postfix start
```

The mail sent by username@ejemplo.org will use as the sender pepe1@ejemplo.org
And mail sent to pepe1@ejemplo.org them will be sent to username@ejemplo.org.